# Max-height doesn't work as expected on table heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I thought this might have come up on SO before, but if it has, I can't find it!

I'm trying to limit the height of my table heading (`th`) because of the style applied by jQueryUI. Unfortunately `max-height` doesn't appear to work.

My table stretches to the maximum height and width available and the heading has an awful looking strip above and below the jQueryUI background image.

Why does it do this, and is there a workaround that doesn't involve re-writing huge chunks of code?

Making changes to the way the background image is displayed isn't a solution because the end user is able to control the jQueryUI theme, and these background images behave differently per theme (basically it can break other themes).

If you want to test any changes for a different theme, you can find the links to the themes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-ui-css-from-googles-cdn).

Here's my code (run the code snippet in full window to see the issue): http://jsfiddle.net/cj9t1wdq/

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:90%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
    max-height:100px;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table class="ContainerDiv" id="Panel_7">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="ui-widget-header" colspan="9">
                <h2>Line Items </h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Line Item Index</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Reference</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Barcode</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 1 Actual</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 1 Planned</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 2 Actual</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 2 Planned</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 3 Actual</th>
            <th class="ui-widget-header">Size 3 Planned</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>261264</td>
            <td>261264</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>261265</td>
            <td>261265</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>261266</td>
            <td>261266</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>261267</td>
            <td>261267</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>261268</td>
            <td>261268</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript solutions considered too, as long as they're not too clunky.

Comment: what about using `background-size: cover` on the th? that way the size of the background image would cover the whole element height

Comment: *In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.* - [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-height)

Comment: @allienato see paragraph 5 of my question :)

Comment: oh ok sorry, missed that. then yeah you'd need to do what COOOL's suggested and change the markup a bit

Comment: @Pangloss I figured that was the case. How annoying...

Comment: @Pangloss I would expect the `TH` to have a maximum height and then then the `TD` to make up the rest of the height required to fill the space.

Comment: @JamieBarker I added `<tr style="height:0;">` for the `th` rows, see if that works for you - http://jsfiddle.net/cj9t1wdq/3/

Comment: @Pangloss That, is an idea that will work perfectly. Put it in answer so I can kiss it with a +1 and a shiny green tick please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-height):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

In your case, you could set a very small `height` to the `<tr>` tag that contains the `<th>` tags.

`<tr style="height:0;">`, it will push the row to its minimal height to fit the content inside.

Updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cj9t1wdq/3/

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not possible within a `<th>` directly as the height of `<th>` is defined as -- “*the minimum height required by the content*”.

**Suggestions**:

**0.)** [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130049/alternative-to-table-layout-in-html) use [tables](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html).

**1.)** Nest a `<div>` within your `<th>` and define your `max-height` property there. Transfer your classes associated to `<th>` to this inner nested `<div>` so you can access.

Is it complaint? Yes! *Table cells may contain divs, and divs may contain divs.*

**2.)** Wrap the `table` in a `<div>` and give the `max-height` to this div.

*Do not add display `table-cell` to these divs as their properties will be overridden to that of default table CSS2 (first comment above)*

**Also, what about?**

```
    <th height="60"><!-- not using CSS but inline HTML? -->
    <th style="line-height:300px;"><!-- using line-height? -->
    <th style="display:block; min-height:200px; "><!-- toggling display block -->
```

Comment: **0)** Not an option, I need a tabular layout with colspans. **1)** If I do that, the the text won't be vertically centred, plus it doesn't quite work (http://jsfiddle.net/cj9t1wdq/1/). **2)** the table can't have a fixed height. it's embedded within a responsive web page. Thank you though.

Comment: Also, your [second link](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html) is because back in the day, everyone used tables to lay out their whole website, because once-upon-a-time it was the only available option. You'll notice that the web page has a copyright of 2004. Context is always valuable, and besides, I'm displaying tabular data (second section) ;)

Comment: @JamieBarker if it's responsive you may have to trigger a few tables, because tables really aren't that flexible :/

Comment: It is responsive, however unfortunately it's tabular data :/

Comment: You gotta redo it in divs, dude :(

Comment: Redoing it in non-table elements would just require `display:table`, `display:table-cell` etc. Not only that, you can't force `colspan` with CSS so again it's not an option. Have a +1 for effort though, none of your suggestions were stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe max-height's are not compatible with `<th>`

Alternatively, you could simply set the height of the `<th>` and set overflow to hidden, ie;

```
th {
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden
}
```

Or even wrap the `<tr>` in a `<div>`, then set max-height.

Comment: I want them to shrink when the table is resized smaller, but just not get too large. Doing that just fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/cj9t1wdq/2/. Also to wrap a `th` with a `div` is invalid html.